# Node.js Creating a file and folder in a Team Drive via API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I can't seem to find any clear example that shows what I'm doing wrong that's also in JS/Node.js. Here is the code I'm using. Note that I can make folders and files in the regular User drive, I just can't seem to figure out how to work with Team Drives.

```
const service = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: client });
let fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'test folder',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
      };
service.files.create({
        resource: {
          'name': 'test folder',
          'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
          teamDriveId: CONFIG_TEAMDRIVE_ID,
          parents: [{CONFIG_TEAMDRIVE_ID}]          
        },
        fields: 'id',
        supportsTeamDrives: true
      }, (err, file) => {
        if (err) {
          // handle error
          console.error(err);
        } else {
// Fluff
        }
      }
      );
```

CONFIG_TEAMDRIVE_ID is the string from the URL of the Team Drive itself.

Comment: Are you using the [Teamdrives.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/teamdrives/create)?

Comment: I did try `service.teamdrive.create` once I think. The documentation you linked, which I've read previously, isn't very clear for how the code should be written in NodeJS, and I don't have enough experience to work with docs at anything other than verbatim.